# v8 and CDT debugging javascript code, how to pause in the function?

Tags: c++, debugging, eclipse-cdt, v8, embedded-v8

I can place a breakpoint anywhere outside the function, but when I place a breakpoint inside the function and try to execute there, it will fail

Or if I just try to step into the function, it also fails, even if I press the pause button in the upper right corner, it doesn't stop at the function, the whole program seems to be stuck.

The normal Protocol monitor flow should look like the following:

```
CDT Msg: Step into
response: Debugger.resumed
response: Debugger.paused
```

But when I step into any function, it goes like this,:

```
CDT Msg: Step into
response: Debugger.resumed
```

The code for the specific CDT and Insepctor Client is referenced in this project:
https://github.com/theanarkh/V8-Inspector

Has anyone else had a similar problem? It's been bugging me for a long time and any help would be appreciated.

I'm a v8 newbie, I don't have any clue yet.

Eventually, I want to be able to step into a function and stop within it, just like the node inspector debugging.